# How to use the modulus when clearing an array?

Tags: c++

I have a method that clears the multidimensional array. Instead of two for loops, I'm using one for O(n). In doing so, I have to check if it reached the width of the array each time in each row.

I'm trying to use the modulus to see if i equals the width, or double the width, etc. so it goes to the next row. The debugger goes into the second code block when i = 0 and m_width = 5, but that's not correct, so my algorithm must be wrong. I don't use the modulus often, so I'm sure that's the trouble. How can I fix this? Thank you in advanced.

```
// Clear the cells with the requested value.
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{    
    // If the width has been reached, go to the next row. 
    if ((i % m_width) == 0) 
    {
        row++;
        col = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your aside about complexity makes no sense to me. If you have n elements and touch each of those once, complexity is O(n), regardless of how you structure that. `for i in 0..n { stuff }` has the same complexity as `for i in 0..D1 { for j in 0..D2 { ...  { stuff } } }` where n = D1 * D2 * ...

Comment: Also, two loops would not make your algorithm O(n^2).  Perhaps you should read up on algorithmic complexity a bit.  Throwing a modulo in there to avoid the second loop makes your code _slower_, not faster.  Clearing an array, even a 2-dim array, is O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that 0 modulus any number equals 0. If you check that i > 0 before your modulus check it should work correctly.